# How to do Count(), Group with QueryExpression/ObservableCollection Result with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, linq, dynamics-crm, observablecollection, query-expressions

In the original version of this ASP.NET program which is for processing data from Dynamics CRM 365, the `QueryExpression` Result is transferred to `ObservableCollection`, then final result in xml format. Now I need to add some `count()` and group by to the `QueryExpression` or `ObservableCollection`.

How can I do it? May be with LINQ?

Comment: If possible please create an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ObservableCollection is drived from Collection and Collection implements IEnumerable so you can use linq on it.
Here is an example of using Enumerable.Count() and group by on an ObservableCollection:

```
var li = new Dictionary<int, string> { [1] = "1", [2] = "2", [3] = "3" };
var observCollection = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(li);
var t = (from p in observCollection
         group p by p.Key into grp
         select grp.Count());
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I use count(), group by with this?

Comment: Yes, of course, it implements IEnumerable so you can use all linq method on it.